# How to hide camera border?

Tags: camera

I'm using cameras on my addon and I would like to know if it is possible to hide the camera border when we are looking through the camera?

I would like to have nothing visible, like the 3dview.

Comment: I honestly don't really know why you would need this, but try going into the viability controls, or; in the render settings up the pixels dimensions until you cant see the border. but yet again, i have never needed to do this, so i wouldn't know 100% how to remove it.

Comment: I use a camera and add empties with images. The camera work like a 3dview so I need to get rid of the camera border.
Right now I have to zoom in the view to hide the border.

Answer (score 1):

if you disable all overlays and disable the selection of your cam in outliner, it works.

Answer (score -1):

For me this was solved with this: "If the issue is that the camera view (the brighter rectangle) is too small on the screen, then press Home to have the camera view fill the window." from another page.